# apprequest says "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using:

```
 $FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            title: 'Check out this great app!',
            message: "This message is displayed in invitation",
            display: 'popup'
         }, function (response)
         {
            console.log(response);
         });
```

I get the following error.

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

I tried deactivating the sandbox mode. I tried it inside the page-tab and app frames, as well as outside. I tried it locally and on the production server. The facebook-like button on the same page works fine, as well as other sdk-functions.

Any ideas, how to get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app settings, under App Domains, the domain you want to use needs to be added.

Comment: Thanks, actually I had an incorrect url set up for the production and the development-server :/

Answer (score 1):

You must use only one URL that you specified in the app settings.
For example if somefile.php is in app settings you can't use someotherfile.php for your app.